# How to open any https URL in my android app

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, intentfilter

I know intent-filter can be used to open specific URLs in the app. But I want all links to be opened through my app just like a browser does. Unlike launching the app, I just want to perform an operation on the link (eg. store it in a DB). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.
Use this intent-filter for the activity in which you want to perform the operation.

```
<data
  android:host="*"
  android:scheme="https" />
```

This will open all https URLs through your app.